# Why can't I get the ShellShock Bash bug to reproduce on Bash 4.2.0?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shellshock-bash-bug

I am learning about the ShellShock vulnerability and I wanted to test older versions of Bash.
I downloaded Bash 4.2 from [GNU website](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tag/?h=bash-4.2). After extracting the content, I compiled it based on [GNU guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Basic-Installation.html) like that:

```
bash ./configure
make
```

After it finished I run the following exploit to see if the bash is vulnerable:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

But it didn't print "vulnerable" which means that it isn't vulnerable and I don't understand why:

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-4.2# ./bash
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-4.2# echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.0(1)-release
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-4.2# env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
this is a test
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-4.2#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `./bash` instead of `bash`; your current attempt ends up executing the default system Bash instance, which should hopefully indeed not be vulnerable.

As a rule, the current directory is not included in the `PATH`, and should not be, for reasons exactly like this.